# How to authentication and security in Hazelcast client

Tags: kubernetes, hazelcast

I have a question about authentication and security in Hazelcast Client. Which methods can I use to authenticate Hazelcast Clients? I'm using an open-source 5.0 version on k8s.

Thanks
Dũng

Answer (score 1):

[Authentication](https://docs.hazelcast.com/hazelcast/5.0/security/default-authentication) is part of the Enterprise package. With that, you'll have dedicated support.